# Sliding Edge to exact location without distoring UVs

Tags: uv, edges

Something simple, yet giving me a headache. Basic situation, I have a modular wall with UVs and textures. I duplicate the wall and want to cut a hole in it for door. I add 2 edge loops. And here is the problem. How do I slide it to the excact position I want without distoring UVs? If I use slide (GG), UVs are updated correctly, but I can't slide the edge to excactly the position I want. Alternatively, I can select the edge loop and using Transform window put exact location for the loop, yet this way doesn't update UVs so the edge on the UVs stays in the old position. How can I achive combination of the two, providing exact value for location and having UVs updated?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> snaps.

I nearly always have my Snap set up with 'Snap To: Vertex', and 'Snap With: Active'. Then, on a measured model, you can work like a carpenter: wherever possible, taking measures and angles from existing parts, by duplication. You can also have 'jig' objects around your workspace, whose only purpose is to be snap targets, having themselves been snapped to your model.

A version of that might be:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate a vertex, as a target
- <kbd>G</kbd> .. (+whatever) the vertex, with a numeric entry
- And then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slide an edge to snap to the target vertex.

[image]

Then you can <kbd>M</kbd> > By Distance, merge the target into the model.

But for repeated measures, it might be easier to have a jig available to snap to.